# Starting second UIView animation undoes previous animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

In Swift I'm using `UIView.animateWithDuration` to animate a button and some text out of the frame. In the "completion" block, I perform a func called `showQuestion` which is another `UIView` animation. However, the first time the `showQuestion` function runs, the button and text that was previously hidden by the prior animation appears back in the frame, as if it had never moved.

I've checked a few questions on here, and none seem to directly address the issue.

***EDIT #1***

Here are the three functions.

```
    func startQuiz(){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.goButton.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height + 5
                self.languageLabel.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height + 5
                self.label.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height + 5
            }, completion: { finished in
                self.generateFirstQuestion()
        })
    }

    func generateFirstQuestion() {
        var aBase = 0;
        var qBase = 0;
        if(self.lang == "fr") {
            aBase = 25
            qBase = 5
        }
        var offset = (self.currentQuestion * 5) + aBase
        var question:String = self.questions[self.currentQuestion+qBase]
        self.questionLabel.text = question
        var answer1:String = self.answers[offset]
        var answer2:String = self.answers[offset+1]
        var answer3:String = self.answers[offset+2]
        var answer4:String = self.answers[offset+3]
        var answer5:String = self.answers[offset+4]
        self.showQuestion()
    }

    func showQuestion(){
        if(self.isAnimating){
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.questionLabel.center.x = self.view.center.x

                }, completion: { finished in
                    self.isAnimating = false
                    self.currentQuestion++
            })
        }
        else {
            var aBase = 0;
            var qBase = 0;
            if(self.lang == "fr") {
                aBase = 25
                qBase = 5
            }
            var offset = (self.currentQuestion * 5) + aBase
            var question:String = self.questions[self.currentQuestion+qBase]
            self.questionLabel.text = question
            var answer1:String = self.answers[offset]
            var answer2:String = self.answers[offset+1]
            var answer3:String = self.answers[offset+2]
            var answer4:String = self.answers[offset+3]
            var answer5:String = self.answers[offset+4]

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.questionLabel.frame.origin.x = 0-700

                }, completion: { finished in
                    self.questionLabel.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width+5
                    self.isAnimating = true
                    self.showQuestion()
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout? if you do, you must not manipulate the frame!

Comment: Please show your code. It's difficult (if not impossible) for anyone to help without looking at the concrete code you're writing.

Comment: Sorry, was on the road. Please see edits for code.

Comment: @luk2302 Nailed it. Disabled the Auto Layout property and it fixed the issue.